# KeyError while removing punctuation from string using loop

Tags: python, regex, pandas, keyerror

I'm trying to remove punctuation from all the rows in a column. All of these rows contain string data. I tried a couple of regular expressions but none work. Can anyone tell me where the problem is in this syntax?

```py
for i in range(0, 3847):
    #Remove punctuation
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',dataset['abstract1'][i])
```

This is the error I got:

```
       4     #Remove punctuations
 ----> 5     text = re.sub('[^\w\s]','',dataset['abstract1'][i])
       6 
       7     #Convert to lowercase

 G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
 __getitem__(self, key)
     866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
     867         try:
 --> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
     869 
     870             if not is_scalar(result):

 G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)    
    4373         try:    
    4374            return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
 -> 4375                                          tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))    
    4376         except KeyError as e1:    
    4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

 pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
```

Comment: You appear to have left off the part of the error message that says what the key actually was, so it's hard to say.  But I'm guessing the problem is that `dataset` does not have a key named `abstract1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with `pandas.DataFrame` object, you could avoid using the `for-loop`. Instead, use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove punctuation.

---

```
# sample data
dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'abstract1': ['so,me p#nct*!&io* issues', '!@#hfd87***}}|', 't&e%s$t@']
})
```

```
    abstract1
0   so,me p#nct*!&io* issues
1   !@#hfd87***}}|
2   t&e%s$t@
```

---

```
dataset['punct_removed'] = dataset['abstract1'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]', '')
```

```
    abstract1                   punct_removed
0   so,me p#nct*!&io* issues    some pnctio issues
1   !@#hfd87***}}|              hfd87
2   t&e%s$t@                    test
```

Comment: Did it help mate @KhairulBashar?

Comment: It did!! Thank you so much!